# Check when an input text change value

Tags: javascript, jquery

How i can detect when an input value change when i'm filling the input with the path of imagen getting from filemanager.

I dont even know how it's called when the input is getting filled that way. **(After select the image, automatically the input get the path as value)**

I already tried this:

```
$('#my-input').on('change', function() {
   alert("You changed the value of the input");   
})

$('#my-input').on('input', function() { alert('some text') })
```

But this only works when user get interaction with the input i mean on keyup, keydown, etc.

Is that possible to do?

Thanks and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to do this

```
document.getElementById('my-element').onchange();
```

after you fill the value via code as opposed to user entering a value.

Example here

```js
document.getElementById('my-button').onclick = fillInput;
document.getElementById('my-input').onchange = inputChanged;

function fillInput(){
 document.getElementById('my-input').value = "Test value";
 document.getElementById('my-input').onchange();
}
function inputChanged(){
 document.getElementById('my-input').style.border = "1px solid green";
}
```

```html
<input id="my-input" type="text" />
<input id="my-button" type="button" value="Fill Input" />
```